# Binding collection to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to bind my Binding List to DataGridView but not everything is displayed ! That's the code I currently have :

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int[] numbers = new int[6] 
}

public class Data
{
    public static BindingList<Person> persons = new BindingList<Person>(); 
}

...

var bl = new BindingList<Person>(persons);
myGrid.DataSource = bl;
```

Everything works great except for the fact that `Person.numbers` isn't shown in the DataGridView (only ID, FName & LName)!

Any ideas why's that ?

Comment: `numbers` is field, make it property.

Comment: I did as suggested, followed the example @Felix gave as well but I still have the same problem! :x

Comment: [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)`= true` or do you create columns manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try making it a property. Edit:  To format for use in the datagridview you could use the setter and bind the column to a formatted string as in the example below.

```
public class Person
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public String NumbersString { get; set; }

  private int[] _numbers;
  public int[] Numbers
    {
         get
             {
                return _numbers;
             }
         set
            {
              _numbers = value;
              NumbersString = FormatIntoString(_numbers);

            }

     }

  public Person()
  {
  numbers = new int[6];

  }


 // The write the method that puts the array into a readable form

 private string FormatIntoString(int[] array)
   {
     string result = "";

     foreach(var x in array)
      {
        result += x.ToString() + ",";
      }
     return result;
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, I did exactly what you said and problem still persists! ;(

Comment: the field `numbers` is an array.  Are you dedicating columns to each element of `numbers` or trying to put the whole array `numbers` into one column?

Comment: You will most likely need to set the `AutoGenerateColumns = false` then create and bind each column individually.  [See example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx)